# Sieve of Eratosthenes versus trial division time complexity

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

According to this link http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

the time complexity of finding a list of primes with trial division is

```
n*sqrt(n)/ln(n)^2
```

and the time complexity for finding primes with the Sieve of Eratosthenes is

```
n*ln(ln(x))
```

The paper claims that the sieve has better time complexity than trial division.  However, if I plot these functions the sieve is clearly worse:

[image]

This image was created on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) using the query

```
PLOT ( n*sqrt(n)/ln(n)^2 / (n*ln(ln(n)) )) from 1 to 100
```

Therefore, based only on big O notation I would conclude that trial division should be better for arbitrarily large n.
**Is this conclusion correct?**

But if I change the constants the results can switch.  There does not appear to be an asymptotic divergence independent of the constants.  It seems rather useless then to conclude which algorithm is better for arbitrarily large n based on the time complexity from big O notation.  The only way to know which one is better is by comparing implementations.  **Have I made a wrong conclusion?**

Comment: [Check wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bn-%3Einf%7D+n*sqrt%28n%29%2Fln%28n%29%5E2+%2F+%28n*ln%28ln%28n%29%29+%29) to make sure. From `lim_{n->inf} n*sqrt(n)/ln(n)^2/n *ln(ln(n)) = infinity`, we can conclude that the first is asymptotically slower than the 2nd.

Comment: Wow, that was a quick solution!

Comment: I originally used wolfram but only to look at the plots.  It seems the plots are hard to draw the correct conclusions from.

Comment: @amit, If you want to write up an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @amit, Zooming out a lot on the plots I can see them cross.  This means for some range of n it's possible, in principle, that trial division could beat the sieve.

Comment: If you are looking into small ranges - you need to take constants and other things into account. A reliable answer for this is not theoretical, and should be achieved using empirical experiment and [statistic tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

Comment: @WillNess, thank you for fixing the link. I made this post more than 4 years ago. Links break. That's a good reminder to include the image as well and not just a link.

Comment: @Zboson you're welcome, and sorry for messing with the votes. :) btw it's interesting to see how the graph changes when changing the upper limit; also [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PLOT+(EXP%5B(+n*sqrt(n)%2Fln(n)%5E2+%2F+(n*ln(ln(n))+))%5D)+from+10000+to+10000000) is instructive (and then [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PLOT+(EXP%5B(+n*sqrt(n)%2Fln(n)%5E2+%2F+(n*ln(ln(n))+))%5D)+from+10000+to+100000000)).

Comment: @WillNess, feel free to embed images into my question in case links break again in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The paper claims that the sieve has better time complexity than trial
>   division. However, if I plot these functions the sieve is clearly
>   worse. Therefore, based only on big O notation I would conclude that
>   trial division should be better for arbitrarily large n. Is this
>   conclusion correct?

No, the conclusion is wrong, the plot is not showing the entire picture, as you need to take constants into account and function behavior for much larger `n` values.

To check out if a function `f(n)` is 'asymptotically superior' to a function `g(n)`, you need to check out what happens at infinity. This can be done as:

```
lim_{n->infinity} f(n)/g(n)
```

Now, you have 3 possibilities:

1. limit is infinity -> f(n) is superior to g(n)
2. limit is a constant > 0 -> functions behave asymptotically similar, and in fact f(n) is in Theta g(n), and vise versa.
3. limit is 0 - g(n) is superior to f(n).

[From checking your functions on wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bn-%3Einf%7D%20n%2asqrt%28n%29/ln%28n%29%5E2%20/%20%28n%2aln%28ln%28n%29%29%20%29), we can conclude that the first - `n*sqrt(n)/ln(n)^2` is 'slower', when it comes to big O notation.

---

For 'small' values of `n` - all bets are off, and big O notation is not informative for these cases. To make informative decision regarding these cases, you need to take constants and other things (some are machine dependent) into account. A reliable answer for this is not theoretical, and should be achieved using empirical experiment and [statistic tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

Comment: I would make one correction to your conclusion.  For some range of n it's possible that trial division is faster than the sieve .  All the can be concluded is that at some value of n0 trial division will be slower for all large values of n than n0.

Comment: @Zboson You were talking about asymptotic and big O notation, for 'small' values of `n` - all bets are off when it comes to big O notation, and you should make conclusion based on experiments.

Comment: I guess it depends on how small is small.  For matrix multiplication the fastest algorithms have such a large constant term that the naive algorithm is faster for all practical values of n.

Comment: There's also possibility 4: the limit doesn't exist. This can happen, usually when a subset of possible inputs to a function is particularly hard or easy compared to other inputs. We don't tend to worry about this case much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Note that trial division uses division at each step (a slow operation on a modern processor when compared to addition or multiplication), while the sieve of Eratosthenes does not. So, the trial division method will likely have a larger constant. Another factor is the space needed for the sieve, but that will generally come cheaper.
2. Trial division may indeed be of comparable efficiency when the numbers are of order 100. Look at the bigger picture though: [(link)](http://fooplot.com/plot/4mzj0par13). The real use case for the sieve is when you want to check millions of consecutive numbers for primality.

Comment: Good point, for some range of n trial division could in principle be faster (especially if division was not so slow) but at some point it will always be slower than the sieve.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used large enough numbers. The picture changes then:

[image]

The real answer is [***empirical orders of growth***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth). At each specific range of `n` we can approximate the growth function by `n^a` with some `a`. The trial division is about `n^1.4` and the sieve of Eratosthenes is about `n^1.05`. Now there's no confusion:

```hs
td n = n**1.5  / (log n)**2
se n = n * log (log n)

_a f n = log ( f (n*1.1) / f n ) / log 1.1
                         --  10K 100K 1M   5M  10M   100M
Haskell> map (_a td.(*1000)) [10,100,1000,5000,10000,100000] :: [Float]
[1.2839688, 1.3269958, 1.3557304, 1.3707384, 1.3762819, 1.3917062]

Haskell> map (_a se.(*1000)) [10,100,1000,5000,10000,100000] :: [Float]
[1.0485349, 1.0353413, 1.0274352, 1.0235956, 1.0222284, 1.0185674]
```

No matter the constant factors, an *n^1.4* process won't ever beat the *n^1.05* process for long.

Ultimately, you do need to compare the implementations, as you say. But you compare them by comparing their *empirical* (i.e. actual measured run times) *local* (i.e. at given range of `n`, which are of interest to you) *orders of growth* (simulated above by using the asymptotic functions). *Not* the functions' absolute values, especially with the unknown constant factors.

Comment: The wiki link on Analysis of alogithms is very interesting.  I need to read over it a few times.  The part on empirical orders of growth is something I was trying to get to.

Comment: It's always amazing to me that this thing is not widely known. That's why I always preach about it at the first opportunity I get. :)

Comment: The reason I have thinking of TD is that I found a way to decrease the constant.  Instead of division num/den I do fact*den>>n where fact (known as a magic number) and n I store each time I find a prime.  This is a lot faster than doing division (primes are not frequent so I don't have to determine these numbers often).  Additionally, I use SIMD and test 4 numbers at once with SSE (8 with AVX2).  Actually, I have the SIMD part working but not the magic number part.  But it's probably a lost cause since the SE wins eventually anyway.  If TD is faster it is probably over a short range.

Comment: yes, and SE can be optimized a lot, too. Working on 2-3-5-7 wheels, by segments that fit in cache, etc...

Comment: Wheels and testing up to the square root are common two both algorithms.  SE can't use SIMD efficiently, at least I can't think of anyway to do it.  That's one of the few advantages of TD but it only decreases the constant by a factor of 4 or 8 at best.